# Build website causes IIS folder to be changed for that website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, umbraco

I have two Umbraco websites in a solution. I have setup host entries and corresponding URLs in the Project settings.

One of them is a copy of the other and then modified accordingly.

Whenever I clean the solution and rebuild it, it changes the target folder of the first website in IIS to point to the second website. Can anyone let me know, what is happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got it. When I copied the website. I forgot to change the Project Url in the properties of the copied folder.

[image]

I think since the order of building the projects was that the new project was built after the first one. It would search the corresponding website in IIS and replace it's target folder there.